# using Google Apps Script: how to convert/export a Drive file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to export a native Google spreadsheet/document/drawing/presentation file to another format, in that same folder, using Google Apps Script.
I have enabled [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), and looked at the instructions to [Open and Convert Google Docs in your app](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app).

Was hoping I could use [Export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/export) to get a [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) which I could then save/rename using [Insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert).

Trying to achieve something like:

```
var file = {fileId: "1yDe...lD2U", 
            folderId: "0B_...hZ1k", 
            mimetype:"application/vnd.google-apps.document", 
            targetMimetype:"application/pdf", 
            targetName:"my converted document"}
var newFile = Drive.Files.export(file.fileId, file.targetMimetype)

// results in error message:
// "Export requires alt=media to download the exported content."

// I am sure the above is incomplete, but unsure how to actually
// save the exported file, in the correct location, with correct filename
```

**Update:** when adding alt=media to the call (`var newFile = Drive.Files.export(file.fileId, file.targetMimetype, {alt: "media"})`), then the script exits with error code 200 and shows the PDF content in the error message. Similar to [issue 6573](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6573).

**Update:** this may not have been clear enough, I want to convert from/to all of the formats listed in the [Advanced Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app) page, not just to PDF. And the [DriveApp getAs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype) documentation states that DriveApp can convert mostly to PDF and images. Hence the focus on using Advanced Drive instead of DriveApp.

Comment: Any reason you cannot use app script native functions like so: var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(file.fileId).getAs('application/pdf') and 
  DriveApp.getFolderById(file.folderId).createFile(blob) to create your newPdfFile?

Comment: Good point. Should work for PDF exports. I need to convert to all formats listed in the "Open and Convert Google Docs in your app" though.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype states: the MIME type to convert to. For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. For images in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround I now use the OAuth2 library and the direct Drive API.

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function testConvert() {
  var file = {
    id: "1cpAZp...I7ejZW1idk", // Google Sheet
    folderId: "0B_...Z1k", // test folder
  }

  convert(file, "pdf", "application/pdf");
  convert(file, "csv", "text/csv");
  convert(file, "xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function convert(file, extension, targetMimeType) {
  var exportDetails = {
    targetMimeType: targetMimeType || "application/pdf",
    extension: extension || "pdf",
    postfix: "CONVERTED_FROM_GOOGLE_DOC",
  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887569/using-google-apps-script-how-to-convert-export-a-drive-file
  // https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6573

  // var blob = Drive.Files.export(file.id, exportDetails.targetMimeType, {alt: "media"})
  /*
    results in error 200 + content of converted file
    documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/export
    1) does not mention the {alt:"media"} (and without it the error is: "export requires alt=media to download the exported content")
    2) states the output is a Files resource (not a blob)
  */

  // using alternative: OAuth2 + public API
  // https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2
  var driveService = getDriveService();
  if (!driveService.hasAccess()) {
    showSidebar();
    return;
  }

  var accessToken = driveService.getAccessToken();
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+file.id+"/export?mimeType="+ exportDetails.targetMimeType
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + driveService.getAccessToken()
    }
  });

  var resource = {
    title: DriveApp.getFileById(file.id).getName() +" "+ exportDetails.postfix +"."+ exportDetails.extension,
    description: "This is a converted document",
    mimeType: exportDetails.targetMimeType,
    parents: [{
      "kind": "drive#parentReference",
      "id": file.folderId,
      //"selfLink": string,
      //"parentLink": string,
      "isRoot": false
    }],
  }

  try {
    var convertedFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
    Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', convertedFile.id, convertedFile.fileSize);

  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to tweak [this code](https://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf) from Armit Agarwal. The important bits to exporting your drive file to PDF is this part of code:

```
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");

  blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".pdf");
```

Then you can send it to your email by attaching the pdf file:

```
// If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments:[blob]     
    });
```

Check the guide for additional reference.

Comment: Agreed, for conversion to only PDF DriveApp is sufficient. I need to convert to other formats as well, e.g. Word/Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper solution from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765129#comment8, by a Google person.

> Files.export() was recently added to the Drive v2 API, but an alternative is to use the older File.exportLinks field instead. Here's an example:

```
function convertToDocx(documentId) { 
  var file = Drive.Files.get(documentId); 
  var url = file.exportLinks['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']; 
  var oauthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { 
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken 
    } 
  }); 
  return response.getBlob(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. Just use the pdf content as one of the parts of a multipart insert/post.

Comment: Sounds promising. Would you happen to have a working example? I am not yet familiar with creating the multipart insert.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version that I got to work after trying numerous examples:

```
function convertToDocx(newdocumentId,folder) {
var fileInstance = DriveApp.getFileById(newdocumentId);
var fileName = fileInstance.getName();
var blob = fileInstance.getBlob();
        var resource = {
            title: fileName + '.docx',
            mimeType: MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD,
            parents: [
            {
                id: folder
            }],
        };
 Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob,{ convert: true, supportsAllDrives: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function exportFile() {
  var exportFormat = 'docx';
  var docUrl = <Your doc url>;
  var exportUrl = docUrl.replace(/^(.*)\/.*/,'$1/export?format=' + exportFormat);

  var parameters = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
  };
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, parameters).getBlob();  //.setName('exportName' + '.' + exportFormat);
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);  
}
```

This doesn't require neither API nor even advanced service

For Slides to export separate slide as image I needed to share the doc for viewing. For Docs works like this.

The name of the downloaded blob is just export+format, so you'll need to rename the blob probably first