# Is there a way of saving a Google Doc so it has the same unique ID as an existing doc?

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a need to create a copy of a Google Doc with a specific ID - not the "friendly" name like `MyDocument`, but the name that makes it unique in the GoogleSphere - the one like `1x_tfTiA9-b5UwAf3k2fg6y6hyZSYQIvhSNn-saaDs4c`.

Here's the scenario why I would like to do this:

I have a newsletter which is in the form of a Google Doc.  The newsletter is published on a website by embedding the document in a web page inside an `<iframe>` element.  Also published in the same way is a "large print" version of the newsletter that is the same, apart from the fact that the default font size is 24pt, rather than 11pt.

I am trying to automate the production of the large print version, but in such a way that the unique ID of the large print document doesn't change, so that the embedded `<iframe>` for it still works.

I have experimented in the past with Google Apps Scripts routines for creating a deep copy of a document but the deep copy functions don't play nicely with images and tables, so I could never get a complete copy.  If I could implement a "Save As" function, where the operand was an existing unique ID, I think this would do what I want.

Anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: Have you used the Drive "Advanced Service" (aka the Drive REST API)? It offers more control over file attributes, such as setting the id target for an upload action, or bytes/blob content of a given file. I've not tried this myself else I'd give an answer on it.

Comment: Not sure how I would go about calling the REST API from a script but I'll check it out.  Many thanks.

Comment: there is a client library for it, in the Advanced Services dialog.

Comment: It's not possible to have two Google Docs with the same **file** ID if that's what you mean.  It is possible to have any number of files with the same name.  The same file can actually be assigned to multiple folders, but you can't have the same file with two different styles.

Comment: @SandyGood I believe the OP currently has two iframes and two files, and wants to automate the process of changing the content of the 2nd file, rather than it being a manual copy & paste from A to B, then increasing font size. So desired workflow is "edit A, call function" where the function exports A to a file that has document B's id - effectively overwriting the previous B. This overwrite would mean that website C doesn't need to get updated to use the export's id, because the export's id is already known

Comment: Good synopsis. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I delved into this, attempting to set the id of the "large print" version of the file in a variety of ways:

1. via [`copy()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy): `var copiedFile = Drive.Files.copy(lpFile, spFile.id, options);`
   which yields the error:

   > Generated IDs are not currently supported for copy requests
2. via [`insert()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert): `var newFile = Drive.Files.insert(lpFile, doc.getBlob(), options);`
   which yields the error:

   > Generated IDs are not supported for Google Docs formats
3. via [`update()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update): `Drive.Files.update(lpFile, lpFile.id, doc.getBlob(), options);`
   This method successfully updates the "large print" file from the small print file. This particular line, however, uses the [`Document#getBlob()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getBlob()) method, which has issues with formatting and rich content from the [`Document`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document). In particular, as you mention, images and tables in are not preserved (among other things, like changes to the font, etc.). Compare [pre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG7CZ.png) with [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKvGU.png)

It seems that - if the appropriate method of exporting formatted byte content from the document can be found - the `update()` method has the most promise. Note that the `update()` method in the Apps Script client library requires a `Blob` input (i.e. `doc.getBlob().getBytes()` will not work), so the fundamental limitation may be the (lack of) support for rich format information in the produced `Blob` data. With this in mind, I tried a couple methods for obtaining "formatted" `Blob` data from the "small print" file:

1. via [`Document#getAs(mimetype)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getAs(String)): `Drive.Files.export(lpFile, lpFile.id, doc.getAs(<type>), options);`
   which fails for seemingly sensible types with the errors:

   > **`MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS`**: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
   >   **`MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD`**: Converting from `application/vnd.google-apps.document` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` is not supported.

These errors do make sense, since the internal Google Docs MimeType is not exportable (you can't "download as" this filetype since the data is kept however Google wants to keep it), and the documentation for [`Document#getAs(mimeType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getAs(String)) indicates that only PDF export is supported by the Document Service. Indeed, attempting to coerce the `Blob` from `doc.getBlob()` with `getAs(mimeType)` fails, with the error:

> Converting from `application/pdf` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` is not supported.

2. using `DriveApp` to get the `Blob`, rather than the Document Service:
   `Drive.Files.update(lpFile, lpFile.id, DriveApp.getFileById(smallPrintId).getBlob(), options);`
   This has the same issues as `doc.getBlob()`, and likely uses the same internal methods.
3. using `DriveApp#getAs` has the same errors as `Document#getAs`

---

Considering the limitation of the native Apps Script implementations, I then used the advanced service to obtain the `Blob` data. This is a bit trickier, since the `File` resource returned is not actually the file, but metadata about the file. Obtaining the `Blob` with the REST API requires exporting the file to a desired `MimeType`. We know from above that the PDF-formatted `Blob` fails to be properly imported, since that is the format used by the above attempts. We also know that the Google Docs format is not exportable, so the only one left is MS Word's `.docx`.

```
var blob = getBlobViaURL_(smallPrintId, MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);
Drive.Files.update(lpFile, lpFile.id, blob, options);
```

where `getBlobViaURL_` implements the workaround from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42887569/9337071) for the ([still-broken](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765129)) `Drive.Files.export()` Apps Script method.

**This method successfully updates the existing "large print" file with the exact content from the "small print" file** - at least for my test document. Given that it involves downloading content instead of using the internal, already-present data available to the export methods, it will likely fail for larger files.

Testing Script:

```
function copyContentFromAtoB() {
  var smallPrintId = "some id";
  var largePrintId = "some other id";

  // You must first enable the Drive "Advanced Service" before this will work.
  // Get the file metadata of the to-be-updated file.
  var lpFile = Drive.Files.get(largePrintId);
  // View available options on the relevant Drive REST API pages.
  var options = {
    updateViewedDate: false,
  };
  // Ideally this would use Drive.Files.export, but there is a bug in the Apps Script
  // client library's implementation: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765129
  var blob = getBlobViaURL_(smallPrintId, MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);

  // Replace the contents of the large print version with that of the small print version.
  Drive.Files.update(lpFile, lpFile.id, blob, options);
}
// Below function derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42925916/9337071
function getBlobViaURL_(id, mimeType) {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+id+"/export?mimeType="+ mimeType;
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
  });
  return resp.getBlob();
}
```

Comment: An "A" for effort!.  Many thanks - I'll report back.